# `didFailLoadWithError:` Issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, internet-connection

I noticed a weird bug in my web view. I have an app that checks to see if the device is connected to the internet, if it is connected then the error image remains hidden. If it is not connected, I unhide the error image. The thing is, if I try and click on another link before the page is finished loading, `didFailLoadWithError:` fires and unhides the connection issue image. Here is the code I'm using:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSLog(@"didFinish: %@; stillLoading:%@", [[webView request]URL],
          (webView.loading?@"NO":@"YES"));
}

-(void)webView:(UIWebView *)myWebView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {

    NSLog(@"No internet connection");
    _connectionError.hidden = NO;
}
```

If I wait until I see "still loading" in the log, then press another link, all is well. If I press a link before I see that message, then `didFailLoadWithError:`fires and unhides the connection issue. I'm extremely new to Objective-C, and programming in general, so I have no idea how to fix this.

Is there any simple that I can have `didFailLoadWithError:` only run once when the app starts up?

Comment: Basically I'm just looking for a way to run `didFailLoadWithError:` only once in the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that I used was to check for the error code. If the code equaled the connection error, then I unhid the error image.

Answer (score 1):

The didFailLoadWithError is called everytime the web view failed to load, which happens when you try to load another page before the current page is finished loading.

You should try other methods to detect if there is no internet connection, such as using Reachability: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html

Another way is simply calling stopLoading in webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType: delegate method for your particular case of triggering didFailLoadWithError when user taps on another link while the previous link is still loading in the web view.

Comment: I tried Reachability, but it was a total mess and went way over my head. I will try to call `stopLoading` in `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` right now.

Comment: That didn't work either, basically I'm just looking for a way to run `didFailLoadWithError:` only once in the app.

Comment: @OralB Can you call the stopLoading before the loadHTMLString method is called?

Comment: I actually don't think I have a `loadHTMLString` method, I'm loading the first website in my viewDidLoad. Sorry if that wasn't what you were asking, I'm still very new to this.

Comment: Would it be possible to have 'didFailLoadWithError' return a value, and check for that value in 'viewDidLoad' so that it doesn't fire Everytime a new web page loads?

Comment: @OralB well, you can set a BOOL property in the view controller and set it to YES the first time the didFailLoadWithError is called.

Comment: That would be perfect, thanks! Should I set didFailLoadWithError to return a bool value, and check the bool value in viewDidLoad for the view controller? By the way, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @OralB You just need to check the property bool value inside didFailLoadWithError itself. If it is NO, set to YES and show the alert. If it is already YES, do not do anything.